# Как убрать промежуток между <div> и <table>?

Tags: html, css, table

[image: Скриншот]

Сверху блок div снизу таблица, а между ними ничего..

```css
.body {
 margin:0px;
 background:url(/img/bg.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 

 }
.div_body { 
background: rgba(235, 233, 233, 1); 
margin:0 auto;
width:850px;
}

/* header */
.all_header{ width:850px;}
.top1
{ width:850px; height:58px; background:url(/img/top.png);}
.header { width: 850px; height:209px;}
.top_menu { width:836px; height:30px; text-align:center; font-size:18px; padding:7px; background:url(/img/top_menu.png);} 
.top_menu a { text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px #F58900;
 color:#fff000;}
.top_menu a:hover {text-decoration: overline; color:#fff111;}
 /* header */
 
 /* middle */
.middle { width:850px; height: auto; border:0; margin: auto; padding-top:25px; back}
.td_block {width:241px; vertical-align:top;}
.td_padding {width:25px;}
.td_content {width:585px; vertical-align:top;}

.block { width:241px; text-align:center; margin-bottom:20px; border:1px solid #BDBDBD; border-radius:10px;}
.block_title { width:221px; height:41px; padding:10px; vertical-align:middle; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#FFFFFF;letter-spacing:0pt;word-spacing:0pt;font-size:22px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1; background:url(/img/block_title.png);}
.block_content {font-size: 18px; width:241px; padding-top:15px; padding-bottom:15px; background:url(/img/block_bg.png) repeat-y;}
.block_content a {text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #000000; color: #ffd900;}
.block_content a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #fff000; background:url(/img/gl_fl_add_bg.png);}
.block_content a:visited {text-decoration: none;} 
.block_down { width:241px; height:49px; background:url(/img/block_down.png);}
 /* middle */
 
 .footer {width:820px; height:28px; padding:11px 15px 5px; text-align:right; color:#696969; background:url(/img/footer.png);}

/*- Страница материала и коментариев к нему -*/
.eTitle {background:url(/img/eTitle.png); height:49px; padding:12px 10px 5px 125px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#FFFFFF;letter-spacing:0pt;word-spacing:0pt;font-size:20px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1;}
.eDetails {background:url(/img/eDetails_down.png); height:28px; padding:5px 10px 10px 10px; text-align:center;}
.eMessage {background:url(/img/eMessage_bg.png); border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0; border:solid 1px #CCCCCC; padding:1px 20px 20px;}


/*- Страница материала и коментариев к нему -*/

/* Каталог файлов */
/* Главная страница файлов */
.gl_fl_add_mat {
 float: bottom;
 border:0; cellpadding:0; cellspacing:0; width:585px;
 text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;
 font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#FFFFFF;letter-spacing:0pt;
 word-spacing:0pt;font-size:12px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1;
 background:url(/img/gl_fl_add_bg.png); padding:5px 10px 5px 23px;
 } 
.gl_fl_add_mat a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px #F58900; color:#fff000;}
.gl_fl_add_mat a:hover 
 {text-decoration: overline; color:#fff111;}

.what_mat_catalog {
 width: 585px;
 margin-top:-2px;
 background:url(/img/what_mat_catalog_bg.png);
 border:0; cellpadding:0: cellspacing:0; width:100%; height:44px;
 padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
 text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
 font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#6E6E6E;letter-spacing:0pt;
 word-spacing:0pt;font-size:12px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1;
 }
.what_mat_catalog a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 1px #F58900; color:#fff000;}
.what_mat_catalog a:hover 
 {text-decoration: overline; color:#fff111;}
 
/* Главная страница файлов */
/* Каталог файлов */
.img_url1 {float: left;}

/* Техт 01 */
.text01 {
 text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;
 font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#FFFFFF;letter-spacing:0pt;
 word-spacing:0pt;font-size:22px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1;
 text-align: center;
}
/* Техт 01 */
/* vid materialov */

.all_countend
{ width:585px; padding:0px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom:10px; font-family:trebuchet MS;}

.c_title a { text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;
 color: white;}
 
.c_title a:hover {text-decoration: overline; color:#fff000;}

.c_title a:visited {text-decoration: none;}

.c_title 
{ width:585px; height:34px; background:url(/img/title-contend.png);
 text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900;
 font-weight:normal;font-variant:small-caps;color:#FFFFFF;letter-spacing:0pt;
 word-spacing:0pt;font-size:22px;font-family:trebuchet MS;line-height:1;
 text-align: center;
}

.t_title{
 width: 500px;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight:100;
}
.a_t { padding-left: 10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;}

.c_table { width:585px; height:130px; background:url(/img/contend.png); margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; border-spacing:0px; font-size:13px; }

.c_td1 { width:160px;margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; table-layout:fixed;}
.c_td2 {vertical-align:top; padding-left:9px; padding-top:6px; padding-right:8px; padding-bottom: 8px; border:0px; margin:0px; color:#323232;}


.c_down a { text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 1px 1px 2px #F58900; color: white;}
.c_down a:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #fff000;}
.c_down a:visited {text-decoration: none;}

.c_down { width:585px; height:28px; background:url(/img/contend-down.png); margin-top:-2px; }
.p_down { padding: 5px 10px 5px 15px; margin:0px; font-size:12px; color:#494949;text-align:center;}

.message { color:#343434; font-family:trebuchet MS; background:url(/img/contend.png); box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<link href="https://samp-project.my1.ru/_st/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div class="c_title">
 $ENTRY_TITLE$
 <div style="float: right"><?if($MODER_PANEL$)?>$MODER_PANEL$<?endif?></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="img_entry"><img class="img_url1" src="$IMG_URL1$" alt="$ENTRY_TITLE$" width="100%"></div>
 
 <div class="message">$MESSAGE$</div>
<table width="585" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td class="gl_fl_add_mat"><?if($RATING$)?><?endif?>
 <span class="e-category"><span><!--<s3179>-->Категория<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value"><a href="$CAT_URL$">$CAT_NAME$</a></span></span>
 <?if($USER$)?><span class="ed-sep"> | </span><span class="e-author"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s3178>-->Добавил<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value"><a href="$PROFILE_URL$">$USER$</a></span></span> <?endif?>
 | <?if($SCREEN_URL$)?> <a href="$SCREEN_URL$" target="_blank"><!--<s5187>-->Скриншот<!--</s>--></a><?endif?> <?if($RFILE_URL$)?> | <a href="$RFILE_URL$" target="_blank"><!--<s5224>-->СКАЧАТЬ!<!--</s>--></a> ($RFILE_SIZE$)<?endif?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="what_mat_catalog"><span class="e-reads"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s3177>-->Просмотров<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value">$READS$</span></span><span class="ed-sep"> | </span><span class="e-loads"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s3181>-->Загрузок<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value">$LOADS$</span></span>
 <?if($COMMENTS_NUM$)?><span class="ed-sep"> | </span><span class="e-comments"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s3039>-->Комментарии<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value">$COMMENTS_NUM$</span></span><?endif?>
 <?if($RATING$)?><span class="ed-sep"> | </span><span class="e-rating"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s3119>-->Рейтинг<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value"><span id="entRating$ID$">$RATING$</span>/<span id="entRated$ID$">$RATED$</span></span></span><?endif?>
 <?if($TAGS$)?><span class="ed-sep"> | </span><span class="e-tags"><span class="ed-title"><!--<s5308>-->Теги<!--</s>-->:</span> <span class="ed-value">$TAGS$</span></span><?endif?></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Запустил пример - отступа нет. Это весь CSS? Может есть другие стили которые перетирают указанные?

Comment: Да это весь Css, когда тут запускаю тоже нету. а в браузере есть!

Comment: покажите ссылку на сайт

Comment: возможно отрабатывает какойто js?

Comment: тоже есть такие подозрения. Юкоз пихает рекламу между этими блоками, у меня addblock. возможно он криво удаяет ее.

Comment: https://samp-project.my1.ru/load/skripty/lua_skripty/nitro_dlja_samp_lua/4-1-0-20

Comment: А сброс стандартных стилей сделан?